# In C#, is it possible to enforce applying Attributes onto Classes implementing a specified Interface?

Tags: c#, inheritance

Let's say we have a custom attribute, interface and a couple of classes defined in C#, like so:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
class TestAttribute : Attribute {}

interface ITestInterface {
    void PrintInternals();
}

[Test]
class TestClass : ITestInterface {
    private string Internals { get; set; }
    
    public TestClass(string initialString) {
        Internals = initialString;
    }
    
    public void PrintInternals() {
        Console.WriteLine(Internals);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to enforce that TestAttribute can be applied only to classes implementing ITestInterface? (The intent of this is that the attribute can provide extra info needed for automated class registration, for example to map enum values onto types.)

Comment: Have you read https://theburningmonk.com/2010/08/dotnet-tips-restricting-attribute-usage-to-specific-type/?

Comment: Not compile-time; you'd have to do some post-processing step; your best bet is probably a Roslyn Analyzer for an integrated experience.

Comment: @itsme86: I didn't, thanks! Looks like it's indeed not possible, unless analyzers suggested by CoolBots or .NET 5 code generators are used. Oh well.

Comment: You always need other code to actually use those attributes  Like a test runner by the looks of it.  *That* code can certainly complain.

Comment: And it does, I just wanted to make sure that whoever writes that code gets hit with a compile-time error right away if it's possible to constrain it with little effort. (New classes in question aren't added too often, so I wouldn't go as far as to create a separate analyzer to catch this.)